# FullCalendar local set to 'fa' now working completely

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, fullcalendar, persian-calendar

after setting fullcalendar local to 'fa',

the name of days will be change correctly
for example monday name changed to 'دوشنبه'

but the title of calendar not changed to persian (fa local) calendar.
for example it must change from 18/07/2019 to 27/04/1398

in angular .ts file:

```
events = [
    {
      "title": "All Day Event",
      "start": "2019-07-19",
      editable: true,
      dragOpacity: .11
    },
    {
      "title": "All Day Event",
      "start": "2019-07-17",
      editable: true,
      dragOpacity: .11
    }
]

header = {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
};
```

and inside of html page:

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]= "header" locale="fa"> </p-schedule>
```

package.json:

```
"fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
"primeicons": "^1.0.0",
"primeng": "^5.2.7",
"primeui": "^4.1.15",
```

index.html:

```
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.css'>
  <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
  <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/locale-all.js'></script>
```

[image: title in local="en" is correct]

[image: title in local="fa" must be "تیر ۱۳۹۸" and today must be 27]

title in local="en" is correct

title in local="fa" must be "تیر ۱۳۹۸" and today must be 27-04-1398
[image: this is demo from fullcalender]

it must change like demo from fullcalendar

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: im useing fullcalendar in Primeng framwork. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/schedule . <p-schedule [events]="events" locale="fa"></p-schedule>

Comment: Can you show some code what did you do? So people can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Persian calendar is not fully supported by fullcalendar version 3, there is an open request to add that:

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4782#issuecomment-513375648

use version ^4

Answer (score 0):

Some header button need to be translated manually.
insert this att. in HTML tag, for custom text:

```
[buttonText]="{
    today:    'today',
    month:    'month',
    week:     'week',
    day:      'day',
    list:     'list'
  }"
```

Comment: yes header is added, i mean today time  was not changed from 2019/07/18 to 1398/04/27

Comment: i just want title show persian date "1398/04/27" in title and day of 27 set as today insted of 18